# Custom grails and flex build for different environments

Tags: apache-flex, grails, air

I would like to issue one command to build both a grails and a flex project (the Flex project can be built with Ant). I have a file, WEB-INF/flex/services-config.xml which needs to be different for the PROD war build and the DEV environment.

I'm thinking of having two files: services-config-PROD.xml and services-config-DEV.xml and then copying the relevant one to services-config.xml whenever a build happens.

So in dev I run 'grails run-app' and it copies the file and runs the app; and for prod I run 'grails war' (or some other command) and it copies the file, creates a war, and also calls the Flex project to build via its Ant build file.

What would be the best way to acheive this, or at least any part of what I'm asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems overly complicated.  Why do you need the services-config?  Personally, I never use it, I use code to create my services which can be done dynamically if needed.  If you want one for prod or dev, you can all do it within code.

I would imagine that prod and dev is just 2 different server urls?  I normally let html pass those urls using FlashVars.  That way, both servers can point to exactly the same swf (or different swf versions), but just change that one FlashVar to make the application point at a different location.

Comment: Thanks, it's a good idea but the problem is that I'm using Air so there are no flashvars.

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't see the tag :)  Another solution is by using compiler conditionals.  Since you're using ANT to build it, you can add the extra compiler argument that compiles both versions of the project depending on the condition.  Here's a tutorial how to do it: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_21.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that on the Flex side. The Grails side is still outstanding but I'll work that out separately. Actually I only added the Air tag after your response :-).